# Android create Listener onLongClick for listview

Tags: android, android-listview

in my application i have one activity with some fragments. one of this fragments i have list view and **i want to create Listener to listening onLongClick on Listview items from activity**, for example if end-user press long click on listview items into Fragment i must be show Toast in activity

for this action i'm create interface Listener such as:

```
public interface IOnLongClickReceiveSmsMaster {

    public void onLogin(Integer position);
}
```

in Activity i'm create `BroadcastReceiver` as :

method:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(M.ACTION_BROADCAST_LONGCLICK_LISTVIEW);
registerReceiver(NotifyLongClickOnItems, filter);
```

Broadcast function:

```
   private final BroadcastReceiver NotifyLongClickOnItems = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        Toast.makeText(MainView.this, "LongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

now into Fragment i must be set defined interface to `LongClick` :

```
    private static IOnLongClickReceiveSmsMaster mOnLongClickReceiveSmsMaster;
    public View onCreateView( ... ){
    listview= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listview.setOnLongListener(new IOnLongClickReceiveSmsMaster() {

        @Override
        public void onLogin(Integer position) {


        }

    });
   };
   .
   .
   .
   }

public static void setOnLongListener(IOnLongClickReceiveSmsMaster l) {
    mOnLongClickReceiveSmsMaster = l;
}
```

unfortutaley my code is not correct and i get this error:

```
The method setOnLongListener(new IOnLongClickReceiveSmsMaster(){}) is undefined for the type ListView
```

i think my analysis for have this ability is not correct, please help me to resolve that

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a lot easier if you just used [`AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html). This is how:

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
    public boolean onItemLongClick(    AdapterView<?> arg0,    View v,    int position,    long id){
        /* Do whatever you want here, e.g. go to next Activity etc. */
        return false;
    }
};
```

To notify your `Activity`, create an interface inside your `Fragment` class

```
public interface LongClickNotifier{
    public void notifyOnLongClick(int position, View v);
}
```

and have your `Activity` implement this interface

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LongClickNotifier{

    ...
    ...

     @Override
     public void notifyOnLongClick(int position, View v){

         /* Do whatever you want here with "position" and "v". */
     }
}
```

Now in your `Fragment`,

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
    public boolean onItemLongClick(    AdapterView<?> arg0,    View v,    int position,    long id){
        ((LongClickNotifier)getActivity()).notifyOnLongClick(position, v);
        return false;
    }
};
```

And there you go! No need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` or anything else!

Comment: listView in into Fragment and i want to create Listener for listen for that from activity

Comment: thanks, i get this error in activity `Syntax error on token "LongClickNotifier", { expected after this token`

Comment: add the opening brace `{` to your `Activity` class :)

Comment: OH work fine sir thanks :) after long click list view itemt content like single click on listview items, how to disable that?

Comment: i'm change false to true in `setOnItemLongClickListener` worke fine sir, very thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you just take List view object.

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yout_list_view_layout_id_here);
```

After that, just define a listener to list view.

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
            Log.v("List view long clicked ","position : " + pos);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: listView in into Fragment and i want to create Listener for listen for that from activity

Comment: You want to show toast. It can be shown in fragment also. Either you implement listener in fragment and  you can pass activity context into fragment and use that context to do any operation.